# SQL Server temp table failure due to zombie state object

Tags: sql-server, sas

I'm trying to (implicitly) create a temp table in SQL server 2014 (12.0.4100.1), using the following code:

```
proc sql;
create table UNDEAD."##_28DaysLater"n as 
  select * from UNDEAD.inv_overrides;
```

UNDEAD is an OLEDB libref, and the code is running on SAS 9.3_M2 (Windows).  The error I am getting is below:

> ERROR: Cursor extended fetch error: IRowset::GetNextRows failed. : The
>   object is in a zombie state. An object may enter a zombie 
>          state when either ITransaction::Commit or ITransaction::Abort is called, or when a storage object was created and not yet 
>          released.

The full log (with sastrace) is below, executed in a fresh session of Enterprise Guide (5.1).

**What is actually happening here?**  Is it possible to prevent this error by configuration, on the SAS or SQL server side?

---

```
15         LIBNAME UNDEAD OLEDB
16           PROPERTIES=('Integrated Security'=SSPI 'Persist Security Info'=True 'initial catalog'=BDS)
17           DATASOURCE='Kernkraft400' PROVIDER=SQLNCLI11.1 SCHEMA=dbo connection=shared;
NOTE: Libref UNDEAD was successfully assigned as follows: 
      Engine:        OLEDB 
      Physical Name: SQLNCLI11.1
18         OPTIONS SASTRACE=',,,d' SASTRACELOC=SASLOG NOSTSUFFIX;


19         proc sql;
20         create table UNDEAD."##_28DaysLater"n as
21           select * from UNDEAD.inv_overrides;

OLEDB_13: Prepared: on connection 3
SELECT * FROM "dbo"."inv_overrides"

OLEDB: AUTOCOMMIT turned ON for connection id 4
OLEDB:  *-*-*-*-*-*-* COMMIT *-*-*-*-*-*-* on connection 4
OLEDB: AUTOCOMMIT turned OFF for connection id 4
OLEDB: AUTOCOMMIT turned ON for connection id 4
OLEDB:  *-*-*-*-*-*-* COMMIT *-*-*-*-*-*-* on connection 4
NOTE: SAS variable labels, formats, and lengths are not written to DBMS tables.

OLEDB_14: Executed: on connection 3
SELECT * FROM "dbo"."inv_overrides"

OLEDB: AUTOCOMMIT turned ON for connection id 3
OLEDB:  *-*-*-*-*-*-* COMMIT *-*-*-*-*-*-* on connection 3

OLEDB_15: Executed: on connection 3
CREATE TABLE "dbo"."##_28DaysLater" ("TECH_FROM_DTTM" datetime2(3),"MSF_BK" varchar(400),"COLUMN_NM" varchar(32),"OVERRIDE_VALUE" 
varchar(1000),"APPLY_IND" varchar(3),"TECH_TO_DTTM" datetime2(3))

OLEDB: AUTOCOMMIT turned OFF for connection id 3
OLEDB:  *-*-*-*-*-*-* COMMIT *-*-*-*-*-*-* on connection 3

OLEDB_16: Prepared: on connection 3
INSERT INTO "dbo"."##_28DaysLater" ("TECH_FROM_DTTM","MSF_BK","COLUMN_NM","OVERRIDE_VALUE","APPLY_IND","TECH_TO_DTTM")  VALUES ( ? 
, ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )


OLEDB_17: Executed: on connection 3
INSERT INTO "dbo"."##_28DaysLater" ("TECH_FROM_DTTM","MSF_BK","COLUMN_NM","OVERRIDE_VALUE","APPLY_IND","TECH_TO_DTTM")  VALUES ( ? 
, ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )

ERROR: Cursor extended fetch error: IRowset::GetNextRows failed. : The object is in a zombie state. An object may enter a zombie 
       state when either ITransaction::Commit or ITransaction::Abort is called, or when a storage object was created and not yet 
       released.
OLEDB:  Performing ROLLBACK on connection 3
OLEDB:  *-*-*-*-*-*-* ROLLBACK *-*-*-*-*-*-*
OLEDB:  *-*-*-*-*-*-* ROLLBACK *-*-*-*-*-*-* on connection 3
NOTE:  SUCCESSFUL INSERT of 1 ROWS
WARNING: File deletion failed for UNDEAD.'##_28DaysLater'n.DATA.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staking the existence of a grave problem on the SQL Server side, I reincarnated the table via SASWORK and the log moaned no more:

```
data; 
  set UNDEAD.inv_overrides;
run;
proc sql;
create table UNDEAD."##_28DaysLater"n as 
  select * from &syslast;
```

> NOTE: Table UNDEAD.'##_28DaysLater'n created, with 4 rows and 6
>   columns.